# Is this true? $Re\int{f(z)dz}=\int{Re(f(z))dz}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I have to say if this is true or not and why.

Let f a complex function, then $$Re\int_{\gamma}{f(z)dz}=\int_{\gamma}{Re(f(z))dz}$$

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: How about $dz$? Try integrating along an arc of the unit cicle $z=e^{i \theta}$.

Comment: Consider that the imaginary part of $f(z)$ could integrate to a real value, or vice versa. It depends a lot on the path $\gamma$.

Answer (score 3):

$$Re\int_{\gamma}{\frac{i}{z}\text{ } dz}=-2\pi$$

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}-Re\frac{1}{e^{it} }dt=\int_{0}^{2\pi}-costdt=0$$

Comment: Isn't the second line should be $-\pi$?

Answer (score 1):

$dz$ is complex for a general path $\gamma$.  Your statement would be true if $\gamma$ was on the real line.  The point is that for two complex numbers $a$ and $b$, $Re(ab) \neq Re(a)b$.  Indeed, they are equal iff $b$ is real.